# interactive map not working in IE7

Tags: css, javascript

I am trying to build an interactive map using an imagemap and jquery.  I have it completed and it works great in FireFox but IE7 is causing some issues.

You can take a look at it here:
http://www.thecolumbianchicago.com/map/

In IE7 the title of the rollover is not getting the width set properly.  Also once you rollover the tall building icon in the center, the background of the title disappears.  I'm guessing its a CSS issue but I can't figure it out.

Anyone got any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it was the javascript.  I guess IE doesn't like .attr('width') and was returning a zero.  I changed the code to have the width put into the image as rel="width" and used .attr('rel') and its all good now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mess with html image maps. You can use vector based interactive maps with [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com).